# PHP Why is my parent not set when defining its child

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, parent-child

I've been trying quite a while to get this to work but can't manage to get what I really want :).

First thing first, I have a "Scope" that contains "Projects" that contains "Tasks", when I'm gonna show the tasks of the scope, I'd like to show the project associated with that task.

Which means that when I launch :

```
$scope->get_Tasks();
```

It will retrieve the projects, and for each projets, retrieve the tasks, if at that point I :

```
var_dump($scope);
```

I'm seeing everything from the scope, to the projects, to the tasks. So when I get my hand on the task, how can I get a hold of the project for this task, without re-reading the database. I tried extending the class task for the project one, but every member of the project end up "null" like at the end of the post.

I have my project class that has the "GET_Tasks" function like that :

```
/**
* get_Tasks
*
* Returns the tasks associated with this project.
*/
public function get_Tasks()
{
    // If the tasks aren't already set
    if (!(isset($this->_tasks)))
    {
        // We get the super object
        $CI =& get_instance();
        // Build the conditions
        $condition = array("ProjectID" => $this->get_ProjectID());
        // Get the tasks
        $this->_tasks = _TaskClass::fetch($condition);
    }

    return $this->_tasks;
}
```

Here's my fetch function for the "_TaskClass" class

```
    /**
* fetch
* 
* Fetch task(s) from the database.
* 
* @param    array   The array of conditions we want.
* @return   array   The array of objects that meets all of the conditions.
*/
public static function fetch($conditions = NULL)
{           
    // If we have conditions and that they're not in array, we return false
    if (!($conditions === NULL) && (!(is_array($conditions))))
        return false;
    // We get the super object
    $CI =& get_instance();
    // Load the models needed
    $CI->load->model('task_mod','',TRUE);
    // Get the records
    $array = $CI->task_mod->fetch($conditions)->result();
    // If we found records
    if (count($array) > 0)
    {
        // Transform all of the records found as array
        foreach ($array as $record)
            $return_array[] = new _TaskClass($record);

        // Return the list
        return $return_array;
    }

    // We didnt find a record.
    return false;
}
```

Now, in the first block of code, if instead of

```
return $this->_tasks;
```

I do :

```
var_dump($this->_tasks);
```

It gives me this information ( note that the parent is not set at all ) :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(_TaskClass)[28]
      public '_taskid' => string '20' (length=2)
      public '_projectid' => string '1' (length=1)
      public '_userid' => null
      public '_title' => string '' (length=0)
      public '_description' => string '' (length=0)
      public '_user' => null
      private '_scopeid' (_ProjectClass) => null
      private '_tasks' (_ProjectClass) => null
      private '_localisations' (_ProjectClass) => null
      private '_projectid' (_ProjectClass) => null
      private '_userid' (_ProjectClass) => null
```

I guess it's something that have to go with the constructor maybe... Or maybe what I'm trying to achieve is not really achievable this way ?

Thanks a lot !

**Edit 1**
Here's the constructor, which is minimal, of my _TaskClass

```
class _TaskClass extends _ProjectClass
{
var $_taskid;
var $_projectid;
var $_userid;
var $_title;
var $_description; 

// Objects
var $_user;


public function __construct($params = NULL)
{           
    parent::__construct();
    if (is_object($params))
        $this->_init_object($params);
    else
        return; 
}
/**
* _init_object
* 
* Initialise the whole project.
* 
* @param    object  the object containing all of the information of the project.
*/
private function _init_object($project)
{
    // Save all of the informations  
    $this->set_TaskID($project->TaskID);
    $this->set_ProjectID($project->ProjectID);
    $this->set_UserID($project->UserID);
    $this->set_Title($project->Title);
    $this->set_Description($project->Description);
}
```

**Edit 2**
Here's the constructor for my Project class

```
class _ProjectClass
{
// Project variables
private $_projectid;
private $_scopeid;
private $_userid;
private $_tasks;

private $_localisations = NULL;

public function __construct($params = NULL)
{           
    if (is_object($params))
        $this->_init_object($params);
    else        
        return; 
}   
/**
* _init_object
* 
* Initialise the whole project.
* 
* @param    object  the object containing all of the information of the project.
*/
private function _init_object($project)
{
    // Save all of the informations  
    $this->set_ProjectID($project->ProjectID);
    $this->set_UserID($project->UserID);
    $this->set_ScopeID($project->ScopeID);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your constructor code for the task class?

Comment: @ginovva320 - Posted my constructor

Comment: You should also be passing $params to parent constructor.

Comment: @MikePurcell Even tho my $param contains only the information for that single task ?

Comment: I assume the project constructor has the same signature? If so I suppose it's ok to not pass $params, but it is good practice to give parent a shot at any values passed in via child so it can do execute any shared logic.

Comment: @MikePurcell I see what you mean, still, here's the project constructor which do pretty much the same, but with its own parametters.

Comment: I suggest you set those fields after you've created the task, in your `fetch` function. That way you're already in the project and can pass them directly into the task

Comment: @ginovva320 So when gathering task with `$project->get_Tasks()` I would pass the $project variable to the function so I can set the task parent by the same time ?

Comment: Yep, that would be a quick and painless way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Project class**

```
class _ProjectClass
{
// Project variables
private $_projectid;
private $_scopeid;
private $_userid;
private $_tasks;

private $_localisations = NULL;

public function __construct($params = NULL)
{           
    if (is_object($params))
        $this->_init_object($params);
    else        
        return; 
}
```

**Project -> get_Tasks()** ( Note the $this variable)

```
/**
* get_Tasks
*
* Returns the tasks associated with this project.
*/
public function get_Tasks()
{
    // If the tasks aren't already set
    if (!(isset($this->_tasks)))
    {
        // We get the super object
        $CI =& get_instance();
        // Build the conditions
        $condition = array("ProjectID" => $this->get_ProjectID());
        // Get the tasks, we pass the object to set its parent
        $this->_tasks = _TaskClass::fetch($condition, $this);
    }

    return $this->_tasks;
}
```

**Task class** ( Note the $_project variable )

```
class _TaskClass
{

var $_taskid;
var $_projectid;
var $_userid;
var $_title;
var $_description; 

// Objects
var $_user;
var $_project;


public function __construct($params = NULL, $project = NULL)
{   
    // If the project is passed, set it
    if (isset($project))        
        $this->_project = $project;
    if (is_object($params))
        $this->_init_object($params);
    else
        return; 
}
```

**Task class -> get_Project()**

```
/**
* get_Project
* 
* Gets the project associated with the object.
* 
* @return   object  the project.
*/
public function get_Project()
{
    // If the object isn't already set
    if (!(isset($this->_project)))
    {
        // We get the super object
        $CI =& get_instance();
        // Build the conditions
        $condition = array("ProjectID" => $this->get_ProjectID());
        // Get the object
        $this->_project = _ProjectClass::fetch($condition)[0];
    }

    return $this->_project;
}
```

This way, I'm able to get access to my project from my task without having to re-read the database and declare many time the same object which should free a bit of memory.

Thanks to everyone sharing your thoughts and ideas ! :)

Answer (score 0):

> It gives me this information ( note that the parent is not set at all ) :

From the looks of it, you are instantiating a Task object which extends a parent object, so you should not expect to get separate task/parent objects, rather the task object will include members (variables/methods) of the parent object.

```
$this->_tasks = _TaskClass::fetch($condition);

// Which calls this

$CI =& get_instance();
```

Which is demonstrated via the output of the var_dump you posted:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(_TaskClass)[28]
      public '_taskid' => string '20' (length=2)
      public '_projectid' => string '1' (length=1)
      public '_userid' => null
      public '_title' => string '' (length=0)
      public '_description' => string '' (length=0)
      public '_user' => null

      // Notice the reference to _ProjectClass in the following
      private '_scopeid' (_ProjectClass) => null 
      private '_tasks' (_ProjectClass) => null
      private '_localisations' (_ProjectClass) => null
      private '_projectid' (_ProjectClass) => null
      private '_userid' (_ProjectClass) => null
```

Comment: How can I manage to get the task from the first project which would have the parent set ?... I'd like to be able to do for exemple...
$task::parent->get_Title(). Could it be something with the byref (&) sign when returning my arrays ?

Comment: Byref should have no effect. Are you pulling this data from a database?

Comment: From the fetch, I'm pulling data from the database yes.

Comment: Seems to me, that the query responsible for pulling the data from the store is controlled by `$conditions` array. You may want to add some params which ensure you will be pulling "parent" data. Code should outline the layout of your schema (think ORM), so if you have two tables; project and task, then you should have two classes; project and task. The query should include a join (task to project), then you can hydrate the task object with task (and parent attributes, via child extension).

Comment: I see your point, that's what I did not want to do to be frank. I thought that I could have my Scope that has one or many projects, which can has one or many tasks, and that from this task, I would be able to go back to the project ( which launched $project->get_Tasks() anyway ) which is why I suggested the byref&

Comment: Byref in PHP only means that multiple variables can reference the same value, nothing else. I've never seen a practical use for them since >= 5.0. The array you posted appears to be cut off as the array indicates it has 2 elements, it's possible the second element has project data in it. Logically speaking, a task should ALWAYS be associated to a project.

Comment: Upon closer inspection of the array, it looks like the task is aware of it's project, which is good. I suspect there are public getters for the private members displayed. For example: `$task->getScopeId()`, you can find out which methods are available by doing: `foreach (get_class_methods($this->_tasks[0]) as $method) { echo 'M: ' . $method . '<br>'; } exit;`